# Error while inserting date and time to MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, date, time

I'm getting date and time by HTTP GET and trying to write a php code to insert these to MYSQL db but getting error.

My date and time are coming like this:
date=260117
time=180205.000

```
$year= "20" . substr($date, 4,2);
$month= substr($date, 2,2);
$day= substr($month, 0,2);
$dateformatted= $year . "-" . $month. "-" . $day;

$hour= substr($time, 0,2) + 3;
$min = substr($time, 2,2);
$sec = substr($time, 4,2);
$timeformatted = $hour . ":" . $min . ":" . $sec;

$datetime = $dateformatted . " " . $timeformatted;
$datetime = strtotime($datetime);
```

My error is like that:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '21:02:05)' at line 2

SQL:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO pt_position (date) VALUES ($datetime)";
```

Comment: $sql = "INSERT INTO pt_position (date)
VALUES ($datetime)";

Comment: Try removing the last line?

Comment: Still gives error Error: INSERT INTO pt_position (unit_id, lat, lon, speed_km, deg, datetime) VALUES (3, 40.714505, 29.785826, 1234, 1, 2017-01-26 21:02:05) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '21:02:05)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this line.

```
$datetime = strtotime($datetime);
```

If you run this line, the return value is PHP's DateTime type.

```
$datetime = $dateformatted . " " . $timeformatted;
```

After this code, you can run the sql query....

Comment: @Star-Man Still gives error  Error: INSERT INTO pt_position (unit_id, lat, lon, speed_km, deg, datetime) VALUES (3, 40.714505, 29.785826, 1234, 1, 2017-01-26 21:02:05)
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '21:02:05)' at line 2

Comment: add quotes string, for example INTO pt_position (unit_id, lat, lon, speed_km, deg, datetime) VALUES (3, 40.714505, 29.785826, 1234, 1, '2017-01-26 21:02:05')

Comment: Try this? If you have no errors, you must accept my answer... or if error occurs, notice me that errors.    Thank you.....